# Unable to open github on Rasberry Pi 4

Tags: github, raspberry-pi

When I was trying to open the documentation page of Deeplabcut (https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/blob/master/docs/UseOverviewGuide.md#the-options-for-using-deeplabcut) on rasberry pi 4, and the page is crushed and unable to show the contents.
Can anyone help me figuring out why?

Comment: People would probably be better able to help you if you provided some more information. Was there an error message in the console? What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am new to the tech stuff, and i did not know what else i needed to provide you. There was no error messages in console. I used Chromium browser, and whenever i refreshed, the original contents show up for a second, and turn into a white page.

Comment: Can you retry with firefox to check if the problem is chromium? `sudo apt install firefox` to install firefox if you don't have it already.

Comment: I updated the rasberry pi OS before trying firefox, and the issue was solved. Thank you so much for your help axwr.